# Evaluating an integral using Cauchy's Integral Formula

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

I am having a little bit of trouble with the following:

$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}dz$$ where $\gamma$ is a circle of radius $2$ centered at 0. I am trying to separate this or simplify it into the form in which we can maybe apply Cauchy's differentiation formula but this isn't working. I did get this:

$$\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1} = 1-\frac{2}{z^2+1}$$ but this doesn't seem to take me anywhere. Any hints would be helpful.

Edit:

Would it be possible to do this:

$$\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1} = 1-\frac{2}{z^2+1}= 1-\frac{\frac{2}{z+i}}{z-i}$$ and then just apply cauchy's integral formula with $z_0=i$? and $f(z)=\frac{2}{z+i}$?

Using this, we would have

$$ \frac{2}{i+i}2\pi i + \frac{2}{-i-i}2\pi i = 0 $$ as the answer?

Comment: You have another pole, at $-i$, that is inside the circle. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy My trouble is I don't particularly understand what you mean by pole. I'm assuming you mean a point in which we have a problem as in $i$ and $-i$ because this gives us the two trouble points inside the curve. I don't know where to go from here. I just learned about Cauchy's Integral Formula.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Would we do two different integrals one for $-i$ and one for $i$ and add them together? Should the answer be 0?

Comment: I posted a method using partial fraction expansion, which leads to a fairly quick result that might be surprising.

Comment: I guess the problem is that Frumpy knows a "Cauchy differentiation formula" but doesn't know the "Cauchy integral formula".  And doesn't know what is a pole, so certainly doesn't know what is a residue.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int_\gamma 1\,dz=0
$$
because $\gamma$ returns to its starting point.

Next we have
$$
z^2+1 = (z-i)(z+i).
$$

So the integral should involve the sum of residues at $\pm i$, since $\gamma$ winds once around each of those two points.

**PS:** Your proposal to apply Cauchy's formula at $i$ to the function
$$
1-\frac{\frac{2}{z+i}}{z-i}
$$
would work if not for the fact that the numerator $\dfrac2{z+i}$ also has a pole inside the curve $\gamma$.  You need to take the residue at that point into account as well.

Comment: I made an edit, could you check out my work?

Comment: I have done some more work in the OP.